# Alternating series test

Tags: calculus

The series is as shown
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\ln^2 n}{n^{0.5}}$$

By l'Hopital rule it proves that this goes to 0 and thus fulfill its first condition
$$\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^{0.5}}$$

I understand that I have to show than $b_n>b_{n+1}$ to fulfill the second condition of the alternating series

$b_{n+1}$:
$$\frac{\ln^2(n+1)}{(n+1)^{0.5}}$$
$b_n$:
$$\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^{0.5}}$$

Do I actually sub in values like $n=1$ to show that $b_n>b_{n+1}$ or do I apply the first derivative?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try the derivatives. Let
$$f(x)=\frac{\log^2 x}{\sqrt x}$$
then
$$f'(x)=-\log x\frac{\log x-4}{2 x^{3/2}}$$
so we see that $f$ is decreasing on the interval $[e^4,\infty)$ hence the sequence $(f(n))_{n\ge55}$ is decreasing *(what's $55$?)* and you can apply the Leibniz theorem to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Simply differentiate $(\ln x)^2/\sqrt{x}$. Since
$$\left[\frac{(\ln x)^2}{\sqrt{x}}\right]' = \frac{(4 - \ln x) \ln x}{x^{3/2}},$$
we conclude that $(\ln x)^2/\sqrt{x}$ is decreasing for all $x > e^4$ because $\ln e^4 - 4 = 0$. So
$$\frac{[\ln(n + 1)]^2}{\sqrt{n + 1}} \leq \frac{(\ln n)^2}{\sqrt{n}}, \quad \text{for} \quad n > \lceil{e^4}\rceil.$$